# Change of variable for a bijective function

Tags: integration, change-of-variable, injective-module

If I have a function $h:[0,r] \rightarrow 
[0,m]$, where $r$, $m>0$.

Assume I have the following integral: $$\int_0^m \frac{dt}{g(t)^\frac{1}{p}},$$ where $g$ is a given function, and $p>1$.

My question is: If I want to make a change of variable $t=h(x)$ to get
$$\int_0^r \frac{h'(x)dx}{g(h(x))^\frac{1}{p}},$$ does $h$ need to be only surjective, or the injectivity is essential? And why?

Comment: I think you should explain why you even ask about injectivity, and whether you tried to find a merely surjective counter-example.

Comment: @user21820 I just wanted to know that when using the change of variable $t=h(x)$ to change the integral, does $h$ need only to be surjective, if not, why should for all $t$ in $[0,m]$, there would exist a **unique** $x \in [0,r]$ s.t $t=h(x)?$

Comment: I asked you where you even got the "injectivity" condition from. If you are asking about a specific theorem, you should quote it exactly and also state the source. These would provide much needed context for your question. And if you suspect $h$ needs only to be surjective, did you try finding a counter-example as I asked? Furthermore, you didn't specify anything about $h$, so why do you think your integral with $h'(x)$ inside is even well-defined?

Comment: @user21820 The integral is well defined. And they said **as $h$ is bijective, then we can make change of variable**. What I was asking for, isn't it enough for $h$ to be only surjective?

Comment: Look, I say for the third time that you are **not providing the full context**. Only in your last comment you reveal that actually you are talking about some writing whose author **already defined** $h$ somewhere and is using it in that integral. **Where is all that context?** The less we know, the less we can help you. And, no, if $h'$ is not continuous there is no guarantee that your integral is well-defined.